# python class object and variables lifetime

Tags: python

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None # contains the data
        self.next = None # contains the reference to the next node


class linked_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cur_node = None
        self.counter = 0


    def add_node(self, data):
        new_node = Node() # create a new node
        new_node.data = data
        new_node.next = self.cur_node # link the new node to the' previous' node.
        self.cur_node = new_node #  set the current node to the new one.

    def list_print(self):
        node = self.cur_node # cant point to ll!
        while node:
            print node.data
            node = node.next




ll = linked_list()

ll.add_node(1)
ll.add_node(2)
ll.add_node(3)
ll.list_print()
```

1. I am creating the object of linked_list class.
2. After that i am calling the member function add_node() three times.
3. but when i call the function list_print it prints 3->2->1.
4. my question is here is that how is it printing it? according to me it should print "3" only because when i call ll.list_print() the value of self.cur_node is equal to 3. so how is it printing the all three inputs. where is it storing the previous values "2,1" ? please help me out.

Comment: I am curious how you print something without a print statement.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann sure, but that's not in the code either.

Comment: @timgeb Right, I am getting way too confused by this code and what the OP wants right now.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add print. now i did.

Comment: actually it is printing 3
2
1
None

Comment: i am confused how is it printing 3 2 1 none. according to me when i call the add_node() function last time i supplied 3 so self.cur_node value must be equal to 3 but it list_print function prints the all three values. so where is it storing the previous values??

Answer (score 0):

At the add_note method you are declaring new_node.next = to self.cur_node before declaring this last first, but, this is unnecessary. Comment that line! I've added a print to check the progress within that method

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None # contains the data
        self.next = None # contains the reference to the next node


class linked_list:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cur_node = None
        self.counter = 0

    def add_node(self, data):
        new_node = Node() # create a new node
        new_node.data = data
        #new_node.next = self.cur_node # link the new node to the' previous' node.
        print(self.cur_node)
        self.cur_node = new_node #  set the current node to the new one.

    def list_print(self):
        node = self.cur_node # cant point to ll!
        while node:
            print node.data
            node = node.next

ll = linked_list()
ll.add_node(1)
ll.add_node(2)
ll.add_node(3)
ll.list_print()
```

[image]